# How do I read text not in the a table like format?

Tags: r

How do I read a file in to R that is not in a table like format?

The data has blank data for some values. The blanks need to be value.

"About," and "Name," are the only values that will always be present.

For example a text file as follows:

```
Name
Type
Color
About

Spiderman
Marvel
Red
Swings from webs

Superman
DC

Likes to fly around

Hulk 
Marvel
Green
I told you not top make him mad. 

Batman

Black
He is a good fighter and detective

Martian Manhunter
DC

He is from Mars

Deadpool

Black Red
Kinda Crazy
```

The first entry being the headers. 
I want to turn it into a data frame like

```
Name      Type      Color      About
Spiderman Marvel    Red        Swings from webs
Superman  DC                   Likes to fly around
Hulk      Marvel    Green      I told you not top make him mad. 
Batman              Black      He is a good fighter and detective
Mar...ter DC                   He is from Mars
Deadpool            Black Red  Kinda Crazy
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use scan in its multiline mode (for very regular groups of three items separated by a blank line):

```
filename="myPath/myFile.txt"
inp <- scan(filename, , what=as.list(rep("",3) ))
dinp <- as.data.frame(inp, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(dinp) <- dinp[1,]  # use first set as the column names
dinp <- dinp[-1,]        # then remove from the data
```

Second attempt (different question)

```
dat <- readLines(filename)
# Matrices are column-major order, hence the t(). I suppose I could have used byrow=TRUE.
mydf <- as.data.frame( t(matrix(dat, nrow=5) )[-1,-5] )
names(mydf) <- dat[1:4]

#-----------------------------
> mydf
               Name   Type     Color                              About
1         Spiderman Marvel       Red                   Swings from webs
2          Superman     DC                          Likes to fly around
3             Hulk  Marvel     Green  I told you not top make him mad. 
4            Batman            Black He is a good fighter and detective
5 Martian Manhunter     DC                              He is from Mars
6          Deadpool        Black Red                        Kinda Crazy
```

Comment: You might want to add a `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your `as.data.frame(inp)` to avoid the names not coming across properly.

Comment: How can I make this work with spaces. In my real data I have a category called summary and it will have about a paragraph of text. When I run your code, each word in the paragraph is an entry. I should have been more clear in my post.

Comment: You should make clarification by editing your question, not in comments. I think you will need to read these in with readLines and remove or process differently if they have multiple spaces. You should now take the time to edit your question.

Comment: I edited my question. Let me know if you need any more information. Thank you very much from your help. I just stated learning this language a few days ago, so I still have a good bit to go.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to get it working. It took me a bit to understand your code. Turns out my text file had a few formatting issues, as a result of being converted from a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The data that you have listed should be able to be read using R's `read.table` without any extra arguments. It automatically determines the delimiter (spaces in your case) and ignores blank lines. So if you have a data file called `test.txt` which contains

```
Name Type Color

Spiderman Marvel Red

Superman DC Blue

Hulk Marvel Green
```

then you would just do

```
> read.table('test.txt',header=TRUE)
       Name   Type Color
1 Spiderman Marvel   Red
2  Superman     DC  Blue
3      Hulk Marvel Green
```

Note that `read.table` is just a wrapper around the `scan` function, which you can use if you need to be fancier in the way you read in your data. See http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/scan.html

Comment: I believe from the raw data that the OP posted, that it was not correctly displayed by Stackoverflow. Your answer is correct for the original post though.

Comment: DWin is right ... the raw data was correctly posted by OP and SO displayed it correctly

Comment: Ah I see, in that case go for DWin's solution